# Azure Data Factory v2 Mapping Data Flow - ticks () to TimeStamp datetime format

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-data-lake-gen2

Requirement:
I'd like to transform CSV file using ADF Mapping data flow.
I have a string column containing data in ticks date format that I want to transform into Date time.

Source

| ticks_date | batch_id |
| --- | --- |
| 637842420600000000 | 100010 |
| 637834825200000000 | 100005 |

Sink

| timestamp | batch_id |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-03-30​T13:01:00.000Z | 100010 |
| 2022-03-21​T18:02:00.000Z | 100005 |

https://tickstodatetime.azurewebsites.net/

I've tried to convert the ticks value to UNIX Epoch timestamp and used the below expressions which I got from different thread but I'm getting null values.

toTimestamp(toLong(toInteger(toString(byName('ticks_date')))),'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')
toTimestamp(seconds(toInteger(toString(byName('ticks_date')))),'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')

I'm a newbie to ticks format and stuck here couple of days.
Appreciate if someone can guide me to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

There are two approaches you can follow:

1. Create datetime object with a specific value of ticks

   DateTime myDate = new DateTime(numberOfTicks);
   String test = myDate.ToString("MMMM dd, yyyy");
2. Much simpler manner

   DateTime dt = new DateTime(633896886277130000);

Which may give output like below

```
"9/27/2009 10:50:27 PM"
```

Kindly refer the below link

https://devkimchi.com/2018/11/04/converting-tick-or-epoch-to-timestamp-in-logic-app/